# what's the correct way to declare an account for program to receive and store SOL?

Tags: anchor, account

Demo bellowed is what I figure out to make program receive SOL. But it seem have room to improve, especially 'NewAccount', which look ugly, but I can't found property Account type to replace it. I mean I just want a standard account to store SOL, and there is likelihood thatanchor have provide this type of account handy to use that I just not found. The purpose of 'sol_faucet' is just to receive from and send out to users wallet.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("7hNqMLVgoCNGvsSKbV4jt2AVVHywzw3KXuoPpCnXwPzn");

#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Changed data to: {}!", data); // Message will show up in the tx logs
        msg!("sol_faucet: {}!", ctx.accounts.sol_faucet.key());  
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, seeds = [b"faucet", signer.key().as_ref()], bump, payer = signer, space = 8)]
    pub sol_faucet: Account<'info, NewAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually just use a SystemProgram account that is seeded just like a PDA in your program. Something like:

```
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [
            b"vault",
        ],
        bump,
    )]
    vault: SystemAccount<'info>,
```

When you want to send funds from that account you just sign with seeds. Note that you do not use `init` in Anchor for these accounts--just `mut` and transfer SOL to it.

Here's a [program example](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/basics/pda-rent-payer/anchor/programs/anchor-program-example) with tests, and here's a [guide](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/anchor/system-program-pda) to walk through it.

Comment: That's of great help. It work and here is my demo on playground:
https://beta.solpg.io/65b76e90cffcf4b13384cf36

Comment: One thing to note: you should not use 'init' attribute on SystemAccount, otherwise endless error, fixing, error ... ^_^

Comment: Great! Yes RE: `init`. I added a note to my response. Good suggestion.